# how to convert sql server 2008 database to its xml form?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml-serialization

I have a database in sql server 2008. I want to convert it in it's xml format. What I have to do? What is the procedure ? Please guide me. I don't want to write the code for this in any language. Is there any facility given in sql server 2008 ?

Comment: this is a coding q&a site, so if you don't want to code, you might ask in the wrong place

Comment: You need to give us a bit more to go on than that. `exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'SELECT * FROM ? for xml auto'` would do what you want on the face of it.

Comment: may be i say sorry. but focus the main point. please don't find the mistakes if you can't answers (Patrick).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this solution here: http://sqlxml.org/faqs.aspx?faq=29

It uses a stored procedure to export a resultset to XML.  It's an old article but it's probably worth checking out. I haven't tested it out so your mileage may vary.

From the site:

```
You first generate a file with the text-editor like:

<root>
<%begindetail%>
<%insert_data_here%>
<%enddetail%>
</root>

Save it as c:\temp\template.tpl

Next you open QA and type:


sp_makewebtask @outputfile = 'c:\temp\myxmlfile.xml', 
    @query = 'select * from sysobjects for xml auto',  
    @templatefile = 'c:\temp\template.tpl'

The Result is a XML-File!
```

Comment: Thanks alison, I hope this should work, I will try and will come back .